# Remove an array of elements from the Google Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am running an android app that uses Google Cloud Firestore. But when I try to delete something from the firestore, it does not disappear.

Here is my code to remove a array element:

```
fun updateData(userId: String, values: Map<String, Any>) =
                db.collection("lotoup").document("loter").update(values)
```

And here is my code that call the function:

```
var document = task.getResult()
var group = document?.get("lotarray") as List<String>
val group_array: Array<String>
Log.d("myTag", group.toString())
val lotnumber = group.random().toString()
lotnum.text = lotnumber
updateData("*", mapOf("lotarray.${group.indexOf(lotnumber)}" to FieldValue.delete()))
```

And this is db:

```
val db: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
```

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to see if something is wrong?

Comment: Yes. I have tried to attach a listener. Nothing is wrong.

Comment: I'm pretty sure FieldValue.delete() deletes an entire field, NOT an entry in a array field.

Comment: Ok. But in that case how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For updating elements of an array there is special methods of `FieldValue`: `arrayUnion()` and `arrayRemove()`. There is nice example in [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) and here is  the [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue#arrayremove).

I do not have playground to try to correct your code, but for sure you have to use `arrayRemove()` to remove field of the array. I think that following should work:

```
document.getReference().update( "lotarray", FieldValue.arrayRemove(lotnumber) )
```

I am guessing from how it is used with `get()`, that `document` is [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot) and, as I cannot test it, please treat it as pseudo code.